# How does transparent proxy gets created in Remoting

Tags: c#, remoting

When we use Activator.GetObject the transparent proxy gets created but the server insance is not created? can someboy tell me wat happens behind the scene? I mean if proxy needs to be created then there should be some communication between client and server so it can hold the reference of remote object,but in SAO using Activator.GetObject server/remote object deosn't gets created?

Comment: I believe this might be a related question from the same user 5 days later http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026140/can-i-use-interface-for-cao-in-remoting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html). This is how classes are created. Yes, the proxies are built based on negociated information with the server- (client-) side.